# Team foundation server how to extract build definitions disabled for particular project

Tags: powershell, tfs, build

I have many build def in TFS, I try to get only disabled build definitions stated with *MMD_* project.

```js
$baseUrl = "https://tfs.myTFS.net/tfs"
$targetCollection = "DefaultCollection"
$targetProject = "MMD"
# Get an overview of all build definitions in this team project
$definitionsOverviewUrl = "$baseUrl/$targetCollection/$targetProject/_apis/build/Definitions"
$definitionsOverviewResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $definitionsOverviewUrl
$definitionsOverview = (ConvertFrom-Json $definitionsOverviewResponse.Content).value
# Process all builds that have MMD in their name and want only disabled build def seperated from MMD_
foreach($definitionEntry in ($definitionsOverview | Where-Object { $_.name -like '*MMD_*' }))
{
    $definitionUrl = $definitionEntry.url
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest $buildDefinitionUrl -UseDefaultCredentials
    $buildDefinition = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::DeserializeObject($response.Content)
 #check whether source settings are null or not 
 if(!$buildDefinition.enabled)
    {
        Write-Output $definitionsOverview + 'build definition is disabled'
  # I need process parameter is 
    }
}
```

Comment: getting issue in if loop, what could be at $buildDefinition.enabled syntex or anything else more better programmed ?

Comment: Could it be just a typo? You used $definitionUrl to define, but parameter $buildDefinitionUrl to invoke?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to query the XAML build definitions since disabling build definition option is only available in XAML build system. Please make sure that you are using the [Build API 1.0](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/xamlbuild/overview) since API 2.0 is for the new vNext build system. So in the `$definitionsOverviewUrl`, add `?api-version=1.0`.

And the build definition status is saved in "queueStatus" property when the build definition is Disabled or Paused. If the build definition is enabled, there will be no "queueStatus" property. So you need to update your code accordingly.
[image]

Comment: I am using api2.0, still I have not getting output

Comment: How to use it, I saw its 2.0 only from begining

Comment: @himanshuk Add "?api-version=1.0" in the Rest API URL you called. Refer to this link for details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/xamlbuild/builds